# Binding This in a Nested Function with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a question with regards to the **Bind** feature in Underscore.js
let’s say we have the following object "room":

```
var person = 'Bob';

$(function () {

    var room = {
        capacity: 10,
        exits: 2,
        count: 0,
        person: '',
        addPerson: function (name) {
            this.count += 1;            

            var nestedFunction = function (nameOfPerson) {

                //  this is bound to window
                this.person = nameOfPerson;

            }(name);        
        }
    };

    room.addPerson('dave');
});
```

At the line indicated by my comment, "this" is bound to the window. That is expected behaviour.

Let’s say we want to **bind** it to the "room" object. Is it possible to do that with Underscore.js' bind method.

Note: I am aware I could handle this with the good old "that = this" routine. But I'm not interested in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this using Underscore's [bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind).

You can use bind this way:

**CODE:**

```
 var nestedFunction = _.bind(function (nameOfPerson) {
     this.person = nameOfPerson;
 },this);
```

Please take note of the `this` passed as a second argument to `bind`, which makes `this` refer to what you want and not `window`.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/6Mjja/)**

You can also do this without Underscore's bind by using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

**CODE:**

```
   addPerson: function (name) {
        this.count += 1;            
        var nestedFunction = function (nameOfPerson) {
            this.person = nameOfPerson;
        };        
        nestedFunction.call(this,'dave');
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/6Mjja/1/)**

Comment: +1 But, `nestedFunction.call` will not work, because the result of an IIFE is assigned to it, not the function itself.

Comment: Thanks @thefourtheye. Actually, I have updated the code snippet and it's no more an `IIFE`. The code is in JSFIDDLE link below.

Comment: Yes, it's an IIFE and it won't work with an IIFE. It has to be changed if `nestedFunction.call` is to be used.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake Thanks. I'm not sure why I had an IIFE. And my apologies to thefourtheye. But this has not been a waste of time. I didn't think of using Bind like that. I'm still an _ noob. Thanks again.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake I know that, but to make this answer better, you should include important parts of the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not help for the question but I stumbled on this question in regards to backbone.

I was trying to save one model then another on the call back. He is the working end result. But _.bind could be used in any other function you cant access this on.

```
  this.information.set('name', 'Bob');
  this.information.save(null,
        {
            success: _.bind(function(model, response)
            {
                    console.log('Saved Information');
                    this.review.set('review', "This is a test Review");
                    this.review.save(null,
                    {
                            success: function(model, response)
                            {
                                console.log('Saved Review');
                                location.reload();
                            }
                    });
            }, this)

        });
```